# Add tag for powerbi-custom-visuals

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

#### Some background details

Power BI is a self-service analytics tool.

Stack Overflow already has several Power BI related tags (8 in total). Aside from the main [powerbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi) tag, there are tags for specific platforms e.g. [powerbi-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-desktop) and [powerbi-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-mobile) and tags for specific aspects of Power BI such as [powerbi-embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-embedded) and [powerbi-datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-datasource). Custom visuals fit the latter category.

Custom visuals are visualization plugins for Power BI - mostly written by the community and typically open-source. Compared to general Power BI questions, questions related to custom visuals are relevant to a different audience (developers, rather than typical Power BI users), they tend to focus on different topics, and typically require different knowledge and skill-set to answer.

At the time of writing this, there are [119 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowerbi%5D+custom+visual+is%3Aquestion#) about Power BI custom visual development, their capabilities, API and usage.

These two reasons justify adding a separate tag for custom visuals.

#### Tag suggestion

Suggesting to add a `powerbi-custom-visuals` tag, with the following description:

> Questions about Power BI custom visuals: their development, capabilities and usage. Power BI is a self-service analytics tool. Custom visuals are visualization plugins for Power BI, written in TypeScript or JavaScript using the Custom Visuals SDK.

I don't have a high enough reputation to add the tag myself.

Power BI in general, and custom visuals in particular already have [official documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/docs/overview/) and a [developer forum](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/bd-p/Developer). So this is in line with Stack Overflow's [product-support](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) policy ("Stack Overflow can *help* support your product but it can't be the *only* support.").

---

Fair disclosure: I'm a Microsoft employee, working in Power BI extensions development team. This is my personal SE account, and I occasionally contribute to SE sites on my personal time and in an unofficial manner.

Answer (score 6):

I've created the tag for you:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-custom-visuals